# How can you edit and remove unwanted search toolbar?

Tags: windows, browser, tools

Recently "ASK" toolbar got onto my computer. When using Windows I could go to control panel and edit/remove programs.

How do I do this in Ubuntu Please?

Comment: If this is a browser plugin check the browser plugin page of your browser. firefox the 3 lines and then "add-ons". chrome, same but the settings and extensions. You would not use "control panel" to remove this in Windows ... there it would also be a browser plugin. Are you using WINE perhaps? I see no "ask toolbar" for Ubuntu when I google it. Only for Windows.

Comment: hi Rinzwind,sorry for delay. No I am not using wine. Apparenlty I downloaded something and this toolbar came with it. I have a desktop at home which uses windows XP, and I share the same address. So it may have happened on XP which I only use occasionally.

Answer (score 2):

Kindly suggest you to follow these steps and let me know if it works ?

Google Chrome users can remove Ask search apps quickly by going to Chrome Settings, clicking the Extensions tab, and then removing the Ask Toolbar extension by clicking the trash can icon next to the search app extension.

Mozilla Firefox users can remove Ask search apps by going to Firefox's Tools menu, selecting "Add-ons," and clicking "Uninstall" next to the name of the Ask search app in the list of installed extensions.

Comment: Thank you Trickj in both cases there is no app showing for Ask. I am really frustrated about this. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Dear Dave, I can understand your situation. Could you please share the screenshot of your browser ? Which browser you are using ?

Comment: Hi Trickj sorry for delay but my job takes me away sometimes and there is no internet connection. I am using the google chrome browser.I am not sure how to attach the screen shot.

Comment: It's ok, its ok no problem. Email me pop.tricky@gmail.com